# C# Regex to extract after capture group numbers only

Tags: c#, regex

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I have the following:

```
(?:[A-Z]{2}\d{2}\s)
```

This is because my string always starts with two upper alpha characters and 2 numeric. Afterwards I have data that is mixed with words and I only want the numbers I want to take this `AB12 (1,2,3 words, 4,5,6,7,8,9)` and obtain this `AB12 (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)`

I was trying

```
(?:[A-Z]{2}\d{2}\s)([0-9]+)
```

however this is not working. Was I even close in achieving my goal?

Comment: The question is unclear. What are the requirements? Right now, I can only suggest a very ugly [`([A-Z]{2}\d{2}\s\()(?:\s*,?\s*(?:(\d+)\b|\w+))*\)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%5bA-Z%5d%7b2%7d%5cd%7b2%7d%5cs%5c()(%3f%3a%5cs*%2c%3f%5cs*(%3f%3a(%5cd%2b)%5cb%7c%5cw%2b))*%5c)&i=AB12+(1%2c2%2c3+words%2c+4%2c5%2c6%2c7%2c8%2c9)).

Comment: I need to remove non numeric from the parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove any character that is not a digit and a comma, you can use the `[^,\d\s]` character class, and use `(?<=\([^()]*)` and `(?=[^()]*\))` lookarounds to assert the position inside parentheses:

```
(?<=\([^()]*)\s*[^,\d]+(?=[^()]*\))
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%5c(%5b%5e()%5d*)%5cs*%5b%5e%2c%5cd%5d%2b(%3f%3d%5b%5e()%5d*%5c))&i=AB12+(1%2c2%2c3+words%2c+4%2c5%2c6%2c7%2c8%2c9))

The `\s*` helps get rid of optional (0+) whitespaces before non-numerical values.

If you need to precise the context with your initial subpattern, add it:

```
(?<=^[A-Z]{2}\d{2}\s+\([^()]*)\s*[^,\d]+(?=[^()]*\))
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

A [C# demo](http://ideone.com/nRDkcU):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var str = "AB12 (1,2,3 words, 4,5,6,7,8,9)";
        var pat = @"(?<=^[A-Z]{2}\d{2}\s+\([^()]*)\s*[^,\d]+(?=[^()]*\))";
        var res = Regex.Replace(str, pat, string.Empty);
        Console.WriteLine(res);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this was exactly what I needed. I would have never figured that out at all.

Comment: Note that you can further adjust it to only remove chunks of words with no digits at all and keep those with digits: [`(?<=\([^()]*)\s*\b[^,\W\d]+\b(?=[^()]*\))`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%5c(%5b%5e()%5d*)%5cs*%5cb%5b%5e%2c%5cW%5cd%5d%2b%5cb(%3f%3d%5b%5e()%5d*%5c))&i=AB12+(1%2c2%2c3+wor6ds+words%2c+4%2c5%2c6%2c7%2c8%2c9)).